# jQuery UI's Accordion not working anymore

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

A few weeks ago, I've tried jQuery Accordion and it was working perfectly well. After implementing some changes without altering the accordion itself, it now won't work. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Here's my jQuery Snippet:

```html
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            autoHeight: false,
         clearStyle: true,  
         animate: true,
         header: "h3", 
         collapsible: true, 
         active: false 
         });
});
</script>
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        DD_belatedPNG.fix('*');
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

And here's my HTML:

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Managed Services</h3>
 <div>
   <p><span>Alchemy Social’s Managed Service solution works with businesses of all sizes — from brand new start-ups to established multinationals — ensuring that they connect with and engage the right social audiences.</span></p>
   <p>Our teams combine the perfect blend of skills, from traditional digital display through search to creative design. With offices around the world, we manage campaigns and support our clients whenever and wherever they need us:</p>
  <ul class="alchemy-product-list-subnav">
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Full campaign management, from goal setting/strategy through to delivery and reporting </li>
          <li class="alchemy-product-list">Targeting and segmentation planning</li>
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Custom built creative generation on demand (image and copy)</li>
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Daily optimisation</li>
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Regular reporting</li>
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Campaign review</li>
    <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to Experian’s unique and  proprietary data assets to improve campaigns</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
  <h3>Licensed Services</h3>
    <div>
   <p><span>As the social space evolves at tremendous speed, even the most experienced in-house teams can need support to stay ahead of the curve.</span></p>
   <p>Experian’s Alchemy Social Licensed solutions offer flexible, on-demand services to meet every need. Our client services team is amongst the most experienced in the industry, offering scalable support to your social strategies and campaigns.</p>
   <p><span>Alchemy SaaS</span></p>
   <p>Licensing the Alchemy Social Platform brings access to the full range of features of the Facebook ads manager platform, including:</p>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Guidance on how to create, manage, report on and optimise campaigns </li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to regular webinars on new releases, features and best practices </li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Dedicated account management support and consultative advice </li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Create campaign rules for real-time cost per acquisition (CPA) optimisation</li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Effectively refine activity at various points of the campaign cycle</li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Control ad spend at segment level by location or target group</li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Analyse conversion data and integrate with other analytical tools</li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">View real-time reporting to understand CPA and conversion rates at ad level</li>
   <li class="alchemy-product-list">Integrate campaign results with tools like Google Analytics and Adobe Omniture</li>
   </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
  
   <h5 class="blue-subtitle">Facebook Audience Engagement</h5>
   <p>Custom Audiences allow you to target Facebook ads to specific individuals, using CRM data. This approach is ideal for amplifying the reach of your overall advertising, enables more granular Facebook targeting to improve ROI. We are uniquely placed to help you create a long term dialogue with your customers, which is mutually beneficial and profitable.</p>
   <p><a href="http://www.experian.co.uk/marketing-services/about/ems-contact-alchemy.html">Get in touch</a> to discover how you can maximise the results of your social advertising by connecting with the right audience.</p>

   </div>
   <div id="tab3" class="extended_tabContent">
    <p>Alchemy Social drives social marketing performance for brands from across a wide range of sectors &#8211; to connect with more of their customers, where they engage and with the messages they want to see.</p>
    <br/>
    <p><span><i>&#34;Our goal was to not just recruit new customers, but to engage the right audience to acquire quality leads. Working with Alchemy allowed us to leverage Experian&#39;s Mosaic profiling to give us extra confidence when building our audience segments. Facebook newsfeed ads were also a great medium for getting people engaged with the brand and saw us boost page likes by 34%&#34;</i></span> <br/>Chris James, Global Multi-channel Performance Manager</p>
    <br/>
    <p>Alchemy Social&#39;s precision engagement, based on deep expertise and flexible solutions, delivers demonstrable bottom line results.</p>
    <div class="leftCol">  
    <ul class="extended_subNavigation">
     <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-luxury-retailer.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">A luxury retailer combines Facebook advertising<br/> with email to increase ROI by 350 per cent</a></li>

     <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-cit-thomson-sport.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">A social media ad campaign for a travel company<br/> achieves 14 per cent conversion &#8211; outperforming<br/> all other campaign channels &#8211; combining Experian<br/> Alchemy Social with keyword data from<br/>  Experian Hitwise</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol"> 
    <ul class="extended_subNavigation">
     <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-luxury-retailer.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">Drives a 55 per cent boost in fan base and<br/> cut cost per action by 84 per cent for a major<br/> UK leisure and sports betting group</a></li>
     
     <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-cit-thomson-sport.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">Fashion retailer perfects its Facebook<br/> advertising – 150K fans added and a 4.5%<br/>  increase in CTR</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div> 

    
   </div>
```

You may also view the webpage itself: **http://www.planet.nu/dev/experian-project/product-page.html**

Comment: Sorry can't help with this problem specifically, but it's a pity you're not using source-control (such as Mercurial/TortoiseHG , SVN, git, etc).  This is perfect example of when it's indispensable - you'd be able to see exactly what you'd changed.

Comment: Indeed, but thanks for suggesting, otherwise.

Comment: What isn't working? It worked ok for me.

Comment: When you go to Alchemy in Detail tab, you'll find Managed Services and Licensed Services. Those two should be accordions.

Comment: You have a JS error on your page 'undefind is not a function'. Suggestions: place the initialisation in the document ready part and make shure all relations are loaded

Comment: I tried to switch the Accordion script above the Tab script but the tab won't work. I've even tried before the end of the body tag and it's still the same. I'm sure why it's undefined and also all the relaitons are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems some tags are not properly closed.. Try the below html, hope it solves your issue!!

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Managed Services</h3>
  <div>
    <p><span>Alchemy Social’s Managed Service solution works with businesses of all sizes — from brand new start-ups to established multinationals — ensuring that they connect with and engage the right social audiences.</span>
    </p>
    <p>Our teams combine the perfect blend of skills, from traditional digital display through search to creative design. With offices around the world, we manage campaigns and support our clients whenever and wherever they need us:</p>
    <ul class="alchemy-product-list-subnav">
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Full campaign management, from goal setting/strategy through to delivery and reporting</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Targeting and segmentation planning</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Custom built creative generation on demand (image and copy)</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Daily optimisation</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Regular reporting</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Campaign review</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to Experian’s unique and proprietary data assets to improve campaigns</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Licensed Services</h3>
  <div>
    <p><span>As the social space evolves at tremendous speed, even the most experienced in-house teams can need support to stay ahead of the curve.</span>
    </p>
    <p>Experian’s Alchemy Social Licensed solutions offer flexible, on-demand services to meet every need. Our client services team is amongst the most experienced in the industry, offering scalable support to your social strategies and campaigns.</p>
    <p><span>Alchemy SaaS</span>
    </p>
    <p>Licensing the Alchemy Social Platform brings access to the full range of features of the Facebook ads manager platform, including:</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Guidance on how to create, manage, report on and optimise campaigns</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Access to regular webinars on new releases, features and best practices</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Dedicated account management support and consultative advice</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Create campaign rules for real-time cost per acquisition (CPA) optimisation</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Effectively refine activity at various points of the campaign cycle</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Control ad spend at segment level by location or target group</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Analyse conversion data and integrate with other analytical tools</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">View real-time reporting to understand CPA and conversion rates at ad level</li>
      <li class="alchemy-product-list">Integrate campaign results with tools like Google Analytics and Adobe Omniture</li>
    </ul>
    <h5 class="blue-subtitle">Facebook Audience Engagement</h5>

    <p>Custom Audiences allow you to target Facebook ads to specific individuals, using CRM data. This approach is ideal for amplifying the reach of your overall advertising, enables more granular Facebook targeting to improve ROI. We are uniquely placed
      to help you create a long term dialogue with your customers, which is mutually beneficial and profitable.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.experian.co.uk/marketing-services/about/ems-contact-alchemy.html">Get in touch</a> to discover how you can maximise the results of your social advertising by connecting with the right audience.</p>
    <div id="tab3" class="extended_tabContent">
      <p>Alchemy Social drives social marketing performance for brands from across a wide range of sectors &#8211; to connect with more of their customers, where they engage and with the messages they want to see.</p>
      <br/>
      <p><span><i>&#34;Our goal was to not just recruit new customers, but to engage the right audience to acquire quality leads. Working with Alchemy allowed us to leverage Experian&#39;s Mosaic profiling to give us extra confidence when building our audience segments. Facebook newsfeed ads were also a great medium for getting people engaged with the brand and saw us boost page likes by 34%&#34;</i></span> 
        <br/>Chris James, Global Multi-channel Performance Manager</p>
      <br/>
      <p>Alchemy Social&#39;s precision engagement, based on deep expertise and flexible solutions, delivers demonstrable bottom line results.</p>
      <div class="leftCol">
        <ul class="extended_subNavigation">
          <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-luxury-retailer.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">A luxury retailer combines Facebook advertising<br/> with email to increase ROI by 350 per cent</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-cit-thomson-sport.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">A social media ad campaign for a travel company<br/> achieves 14 per cent conversion &#8211; outperforming<br/> all other campaign channels &#8211; combining Experian<br/> Alchemy Social with keyword data from<br/>  Experian Hitwise</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="rightCol">
        <ul class="extended_subNavigation">
          <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-luxury-retailer.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">Drives a 55 per cent boost in fan base and<br/> cut cost per action by 84 per cent for a major<br/> UK leisure and sports betting group</a></li>
          <li><a href=" http://www.experian.co.uk/assets/marketing-services/case-studies/case-study-cit-thomson-sport.pdf" target="_blank" class="alchemy-product-link">Fashion retailer perfects its Facebook<br/> advertising – 150K fans added and a 4.5%<br/>increase in CTR</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79zpkLf7/)

Comment: Hi! It's still not working, I'm sorry for not clearing it up properly, it should end at the last <li> which is "Access to Experian’s unique and proprietary data assets to improve campaigns" and that's it. Maybe that's the reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue. All I did was simply download another version of jquery UI and it worked again. I'm not sure what went wrong even though, the jQuery UI shouldn't be compatible with the jQuery version I have.

```html
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alchemy-product-style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slides').cycle({
   fx : 'fade',
   timeout: 8000 
  });

  //When page loads...
  $(".extended_tabContent").hide(); //Hide all content                                            
  $(".extended_tabContent:first").show(); //Show first tab content 

  $("ul#tabNavigationFourTabs li").mouseover(function() {

   $("ul#tabNavigationFourTabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
   $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
   $(".extended_tabContent").hide(); //Hide all tab content
   var activeTab = '#' + $(this).find("a").attr("rel");
   $(activeTab).show();
   return false;
  });
 });
</script>

 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            autoHeight: false,
         clearStyle: true,  
         animate: true,
         header: "h3", 
         collapsible: true, 
         active: false 
         });
});
</script>
```